# Mendelson's Mathematical Logic: Proving (B ^ C → C) within the System L

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Hi  I am working through Mendelson's fourth edition of mathematical logic ( I will attach the link below) and I am stuck on Exercise 1.46 Problem (e): "Showing that the following is a theorem of L:" (B ^ C → C).    As Modus Ponens is the only rule of inference allowed in the system L, ( B ^ V) is "abbreviated" to be ¬(A → ¬B). Also, the ^ sign represents &.

I cannot get out of the gates for this one. The negation on the outside of the parenthesis stumps me. My hypothesis is ¬(A → ¬B). That is all I have.

https://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/mendelson.pdf   (The problem and the relevant Lemmas and axioms are on pages 35-40. The problem itself is on page 40).

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those nasty problems where you have to keep using deduction theorem to swap between $X \implies Y$ and $X \vdash Y$.  I suggest don't bother trying to construct the proof, just establish that such a proof could be constructed.

$$\lnot (B \Rightarrow \lnot C) \Rightarrow C \dashv \lnot C \Rightarrow \lnot \lnot (B \Rightarrow \lnot C)$$

By lemma 1.11 (d).

$$\lnot \lnot (B \Rightarrow \lnot C) \dashv (B \Rightarrow \lnot C)$$

By lemma 1.11 (b).  So what's left to establish is

$$\lnot C \Rightarrow (B \Rightarrow \lnot C)$$

From (A1), then splice everything together with deduction theorems and transitivity (corollary 1.10 (a)).  Good luck~ (I feel bad for you learning logic from that book).

Comment: I second that last sentiment! Why do people feel compelled to teach logic that way?